# Cannot GET / in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

index.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const exp = require("constants");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;
const app = express();
//enable body parser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'pubic')));
app.use('/openai', require("./routes/openaiRoutes"));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

so I have 1 file index.js and in the public folder I have index.html file.

I am referring index.html in index.js through the path but when I run my localhost on port 5001 I get an error

**Browser error**
[image]

**In the console**
[image]

Comment: you dont have a `/` handler, webservers default to `index.*` express static wont

Comment: where do I need to put / handler?

Comment: sorry I misspelled my public folder. My bad

Answer (score 0):

sorry I misspelled my **`public`** folder. My bad

Comment: Remove answer of typos and put it in the comments.